# Routing the state in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm coding mobile app on ionic framework, my app contains 2 tabs and each tab has own navigation.

For example,

"Tab A" has "Welcome A page" -> "Second Page" -> "Third Page"

"Tab B" has "Welcome B page"

When I click the link on "Welcome A page" the app will navigate to "Second Page" and show me the 'navigation back button' which I can "Welcome A page"

My question is I want to make the route from "Welcome B page" to "Second Page" but when I do that, "Second Page" is not show 'navigation back button' to me.

How can I handle it?

Thank you

Comment: A plunker would be more vocal to explain the issue..

Comment: maybe start from here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/